# Сортировка вложенных списков

Tags: python, list

В результате работы програмы с вводом [1,2,"a"] получаю список [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], ['a'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'a']].

```
def get_combination(my_list):
        comb_list=[]
        n=len(my_list)
        for i in range(2**n):
            c = []
            for j in range(n):
                if i == 0: break
                if i & 1: c.append(my_list[j])
                i >>= 1
            comb_list.append(c)
```

Мне нужно как-то отсортировать его и получить [[], [1], [2], ['a'], [1, 2], [1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'a']].
Вроде бы поменять местами два елемента, но это не сработает на список другой длины поэтому только сортировка. Вот с ней и начинаются проблемы.
Еще один пример  того что должно быть : вход

```
[1,2,3,4] = [[],
    [1], [2], [3], [4],
    [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

И то что есть :
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
Может быть нужно изменить саму функцию.

Comment: что вы ожидаете при вводе ```[2, 5, 1, 0]``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
def main():
    tests = [
        [1, 2, 'a'],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ]

    for test in tests:
        combs = get_combinations(test)
        print(combs)

def get_combinations(iterable):
    res = [[]]*(2**(len(iterable)))
    k = 0
    for j in range(len(iterable)+1):
        for comb in combinations(iterable, j):
            res[k] = comb
            k += 1
    return res

def combinations(iterable, r):
    res = []
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    res.append([pool[i] for i in indices])
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return res
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        res.append([pool[i] for i in indices])
    return res
    
main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
from itertools import *
sp=[1,2,3,4]
for j in range(len (sp)+1):       
    for i in combinations(sp, j):
        print(list(i))
```

Результат:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

При:

```
sp=[1,2,"a"]
```

получаем

```
[]
[1]
[2]
['a']
[1, 2]
[1, 'a']
[2, 'a']
[1, 2, 'a']
```

А если вдруг внезапно выясниться, что использовать библиотеки запрещено - по использовать скрипт, реализующий функцию combinations:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: А что делать если библиотеки запрещено использовать?

Comment: Как минимум - указывать это в условии, что-бы люди не тратили свое время отвечая вам. Ответ подправил. На первый раз.

Comment: Извините. Виноват.

Comment: Так исправленный вариант вам подошел, или еще что-то "запрещено" использовать?

Comment: Увы, нет. Ибо из-за своей глупости я не могу преобразовать генератор в обычную функцию.